# Java Open source helpdesk +workflow project

Tags: java, open-source, jakarta-ee, workflow

Any recommendation on which Java open source helpdesk system i should use ?

i need these criteria
- come with dynamic approval level support for certain request (workflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the java basec Open source helpdesk system are

- [itracker](http://www.itracker.org/) 
  Java based open source help desk application with an emphasis on modularity. It's also provides i18n support.
- [JTrac](http://jtrac.info/)
  A Java based open source issue tracking system.

If you want create your own  Help desk management system then  u can look at Jboss [JBPM](http://www.jboss.com/products/jbpm/) frame work I have worked on it  and done a simple work flow management system using JBPM

Hope this helps !

Comment: itracker  is not helpdesk app . it is a project management tools . i wast many time to deploy it . Then , i discover this bad truth.

Answer (score 1):

This is made in ROR but can be deployed in Java with JRuby : [www.redmine.org](http://www.redmine.org). It's the best free project management/tracking tool I know in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this may be helpful:

http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/

They have a comnunity open source edition.

You can find additional software here, some of them are in java:

http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/

Open source workflow engines in java:

http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

Comment: hmm, can't find any java helpdesk with those criteria ..

Comment: @cometta, then you just have to implement it or pay for one which meets your criteria